# How can I scroll to a specific Y-axis point on another page?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, hyperlink, relative-path

I'm trying to figure out how to navigate to a specific point of a page (ID) from another page and, at the same time, lower the y coordinate to the desired point. For now I have used the simple relative link eg: phone.html#live and it would work if I didn't have at the top of the page a div with position fixed high 200px. This is the JS code I tried to implement but only the first condition is read. Any help is precious, I'm on the high seas.

```js
//code of the destination page

if (location.hash = "phone.html#live") {
  scrollex();
}
if (location.hash = "phone.html#history") {
  scrollexTwo();
}

function scrollex() {
  console.log("scrollex")
  window.scrollBy(0, 630);
}

function scrollexTwo() {
  console.log("scrollex")
  window.scrollBy(0, 1320);
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <a class="link" id="news" href="phone.html">NEWS</a>
  <a class="link" onclick="scrollex()" id="live" href="phone.html#live">LIVE</a>
  <a class="link" onclick="scrollexTwo()" id="history" href="phone.html#history">HISTORY</a>
  <a class="link" id="shop" href="phone.html#shop">SHOP</a>
  <div class="dividoNav"></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. You haven't explained what you're trying to scroll to.  What is "the desired point"? What does element height have to do with it?

Comment: hi @isherwood, I try to explain myself better: I have a phone page and an apparel page. Both in the phone and apparel page I have the menu with different sections (news, live, history and shop) I would like to navigate in these sections from the apparel page. However, these sections do not correspond to single pages, they are all on the phone page

Comment: To answer the question of the height of the element I noticed that if I remove my header that has position fixed and height 200 to host the menu the problem does not exist and the relative link falls perfectly at the beginning of the section. For this I thought that being able to scroll the y axis could be a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a very small delay on the scroll like this.

```
function scrollex() {
  console.log("scrollex");
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.scroll(0, 630);
  }, 1);
}
```

This way you are making sure that the scrollex function only scrolls after the page has scrolled to the place you want it.